# Bad text formatting on iPhone Mail app

Tags: html, css, iphone, newsletter

I have some problem with an email (newsletter) which is in HTML and uses images.
The problem is that the text on the desktop is wider than on the iPhone.
You can see an example here:

On desktop:
[image]

On iPhone: 
[image]

As you can see - the problem is that the text on iPhone is not wide as on desktop.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: @ralph.m because the text in both screens should be in the same wide